Text to Columns not working unless each cell is double clicked into
I have a use case where I'm exporting a Windows event log to CSV and then need to split one column's cells into columns based on newlines.
As advised in multiple places, I managed to insert a newline character into the delimiter field Other: by pressing CTRL + J or ALT + NumPad 0010. (You can confirm that this has been done by pressing → and the caret will move down.)
However, I'm running into a strange issue that seems to be a bug - this only works once each cell has been double clicked into (and doing so ever-so-slightly changes the character rendering / spacing). This is do-able on a small scale, but my actual use case involves files that contain over 1,000,000 rows / events.
Before:


After:


Side by side (before and after):




This exact issue has been outlined at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-text-to-columns-line-break-not-working-until/517a2071-ded4-4129-be14-ae45b1d88bab, but it was closed with no resolution, hence me posting here.
The raw (and redacted) CSV is as follows:
Level,Date and Time,Source,Event ID,Task Category,,
Information,2024/04/22 12:23,<product>,108,Critical,"Allowed outbound connection.
Rule Id: <ruleID>
Rule Name: <ruleName>
PID: 212304
Ip Protocol Number: 6
Local Address: <localHost> (Port: 59660)
Remote Address: <remoteIPAddress> (Port: 443)
FQDN: <remoteFQDN>
Application Name :\device\harddiskvolume3\program files (x86)\microsoft\edge\application\msedge.exe.",
Information,2024/04/22 12:23,<product>,108,Critical,"Allowed outbound connection.
Rule Id: <ruleID>
Rule Name: <ruleName>
PID: 212304
Ip Protocol Number: 6
Local Address: <localHost> (Port: 59660)
Remote Address: <remoteIPAddress> (Port: 443)
FQDN: <remoteFQDN>
Application Name :\device\harddiskvolume3\program files (x86)\microsoft\edge\application\msedge.exe.",


I worked around this by doing the following:

Select the next available cell in row 1, in this case G1.
In the formula bar, enter =TEXTSPLIT(F1, CHAR(10)) (char 10 is a newline character). Don't worry that it says #VALUE!.
Click on column G and press CTRL + D to fill the formula down. If a window entitled "Large Operation" pops up, click on "OK".

The cells should now be split across columns to be filtered on.


